# XPath: Selecting elements having a child at a specified position of a specified type

Tags: xml, xpath

Looking at the following XML-Example:

```
<bookstore>
    <book>
        <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <price>39.95</price>
        <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

Using XPath i wan't to select all books with first child being a title element and second child being a price element. This would return the first book in the example.

I tried the following expression:

```
book[title[1] and price[2]]
```

But this expression doesn't match, because it's selecting all books with at least one title element and with at least two price elements. How can i change this expression to select all books with first child being a title element and second child being a price element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by getting the `title` child and check if there is the following `price` sibling:

```
//book[title/following-sibling::price]
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint input.xml --xpath '//book[title/following-sibling::price]'
<book>
        <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
        <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

---

Another approach would be to check the `name()`s of the first and second children of `book` node:

```
//book[name(*[1]) = "title" and name(*[2]) = "price"]
```

Comment: The first expression `//book[title/following-sibling::price]` does not check that `title` is the first child at all, so it does not answer the question! The second expression is correct, but could be arguably simplified to `//book[name(*[1]) = "title"][name(*[2]) = "price"]`

Comment: @adamretter yup, strictly speaking the first option is not what the OP exactly wanted, but it works on the provided example and besides I like the solution :) thanks